# Missing association bonus?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, linked-accounts

I have received the association bonus in all sites I was registered at the time of first having >200 rep (I do not recall whether that was SO or SO Meta).

Joining SE Math had me with 101 rep there, as expected. But I joined Ask Ubuntu 4 days ago (fig. 1), and the top bar shows 1 rep (fig. 2). The site itself shows 101 rep (fig. 1), as expected.

Is there something I should do about this?

Is this a symptom that something has to be fixed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Caching? If the site itself says you have 101, then I wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: Your [Stack Exchange accounts page](http://stackexchange.com/users/3174390/sancho-s?tab=accounts) shows it as 101 as well. This is just a caching issue I bet, it'll update in due time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I wouldn't worry anyway. I just wanted to hint about a possible overall aspect to check on the site, not about this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [Stack Exchange accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/3174390/sancho-s?tab=accounts) shows as you having 101 reputation on Ask Ubuntu site.

> Is there something I should do about this?

Nope. Just wait a few minutes (or hours).

> Is this a symptom that something has to be fixed?

Nope. It's just caching (as always).

[image]

Comment: Ok, let's see. I joined Ask Ubuntu 4 days ago. PS: As posted, I was aware that the site showed 101 rep, that's why I skipped posting the figure that you did (I mean the first one ;-)). I then thought it was a minor issue, if anything at all.

Comment: @sancho.s: What reputation do you see when you click [this link](http://askubuntu.com/users/226614/sancho-s)?

Comment: 101, that's the image I added a few minutes ago.