# Haven't received association bonus on Arqade

Tags: bug, status-completed, association-bonus

I have over 200 reputation in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533380/mibac) for a long time now.

On all sites I joined, I got the association bonus, e.g. in [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/55144/mibac?tab=reputation) I got it when joining back in July 2017.

Also, on sites I joined before getting 200 rep on SO, I got the bonus on June 17<sup>th</sup> 2015, e.g. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/70697/mibac?tab=reputation).

However, my reputation on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/91833/mibac) is still 1, and I didn't get the bonus there for some reason.

Can this please be fixed so that I get the 100 rep association bonus on Arqade?

This is not a duplicate of [Missing association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213068), because I created my Arqade account before I could've gotten the association bonus, but after I became eligible for that bonus I did not receive it. [Accounts tab also displays 1 rep for Arqade](https://stackexchange.com/users/4326776/mibac138?tab=accounts)

Comment: @Nij Not a duplicate

Comment: This is probably the same issue as in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289134/323179).

Comment: @Laurel seems like it is the same issue but that doesn't really help

Comment: @Mibac: Given that a dev already answered to say "it's tough to repro but we're looking into it", I can't imagine what other answer you're expecting to get on a *non*-duplicated question.

Comment: Did you merge that account with this one?

Comment: @NathanTuggy that other bug report is marked as completed, it's a case-by-case "fix". So it's not really good to close this one.

Comment: @Catija what makes you think it's a merge? I can't see any sign for such thing.

Comment: @Catija oh, but only here... the arqade gravatar is the same as SO and other sites I checked. So don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Eh, no harm in asking for help with an individual case. IIRC the concerns I had back in January have been resolved. (cc @NathanTuggy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that. I kicked off a manual grant for you, and you should see the bonus on your Arqade profile now.

Comment: Why sorry? What went wrong? (i.e. how is it your fault?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not as far as I'm aware, but apologizing for an inconvenience on behalf of the company/software is a common and polite thing to do.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Still wonder what went wrong though?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Beats me. Most of the time it's a SQL timeout or something along those lines. Not really worth chasing down unless there are many failures occurring around the same time (that is, there's likely a different issue at play) when the immediate fix to the profile takes about 30 seconds (including time required to look up the exact route).

Comment: Bit surprised there's no some sort of "catch them all" job running daily to catch missing bonuses and grant them, same way there is for reputation. While not fatal indeed, pretty sure many simply never notice it.